# Would you consider changing the interface or using an adapter here?

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I have an interface that returns an Enumerable of a type.

```
public interface IMapper
{
    IEnumerable<IContract> Get(params object[] objects);
}
```

That basically takes one or more parameters whose type is also unknown and returns an Enumerable of any type that implements `IContract`. Feel free to suggest an alternative for this.

Now this looks simple enough and works. However, here's a scenario where it always returns one object (of type IContract). I can't change the fact that it returns only one object.

```
var escalationMapper = _factory.GetEscalationMapper();

//we only get one object with a list of triggers but the interface returns a list. Change the interface? 
var escalations = escalationMapper.Get(trackingGroupCode);

_factory.Release(escalationMapper);

var contracts = escalations as IList<IContract> ?? escalations.ToList();
response = Request.CreateResponse(!contracts.Any()
            ? HttpStatusCode.NotFound : HttpStatusCode.OK, contract);
```

The line of code we're interested is what follows the comment because I don't feel comfortable returning just one object and calling it a list. **There are other usages of the Get() method that returns lists proper This just happened to return at most 1 object.**.

Is it reasonable to return a single object as a list, or is there a better way to implement this?

Comment: If it's not about Java, then don't tag it as Java. This is C# code, so Java developers won't be able to help much.

Comment: Understood but there's a large Java community and this is related to interfaces and not the underlying programming language.

Comment: Per your problem, it's fine returning a list of just a single object because the point is that your `Get` method *could* return more than one object in the list. If you can guarantee that it would only return one, however, then you might consider changing it.

Comment: Why do you feel ridiculous? Zero and one are perfectly valid sizes for an indeterminate collection of objects.

Comment: Sorry the comment above the code is a bit inappropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in the comments, there is nothing wrong design-wise with your code. Even if the particular place where you call `Get` is guaranteed to return at most a single item within the returned list, that doesn't mean it's going to be guaranteed everywhere else that calls `IMapper.Get`.

If you really want to simplify it so that it returns the single object instead of a one-length list, though, I wouldn't recommend changing the interface to have an additional method, either. This would break all classes that implement `IMapper` and force you to implement that new method, even in places where the new method wouldn't add anything useful. This would be an especially big problem if anyone else uses your code for their own purposes, as it would force them to perform the rewrite as well.

One thing you could do to get around that issue, however, is to instead declare the new method as an extension method:

```
public static class IMapperExtensions
{
    public static IContract GetSingle(this IMapper mapper, params object[] objects)
    {
        return mapper.Get(objects).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Then you can call it like so:

```
var escalation = escalationMapper.GetSingle(trackingGroupCode);
```

This will give you the functionality you need without breaking any existing implementations of your interface.

Comment: Yep that's it.  I am not constrained by not having access to the interface, but this is possibly the best way to go as the contract pretty much remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

It's a tradeoff.  The goal is to fit the type expected by the client.  The tradeoff is between 1) having an additional class and 2) forcing an existing type to change.

The pro of 1) is that an existing type remains intact (assuming it does presently make the most sense as the type it is, returning a single IContract); the con of 1) is that it requires more code and more dependencies.

The pro of 2) is that code size and number of dependencies remain lower; the con of 2) is that you subvert the project's types design by changing a type to return a list that will always contain a single element, purely for the sake of the client's expectations.

In strongly typed languages, the types system is intended to be there as an aid to the programmer.  The greater verbosity *buys* the benefits of the type system, and subverting that system doesn't help very much with reducing the verbosity, yet loses the benefits *of* that type system.  As such, I would resolve this in strongly-typed languages with an adapter, not by changing the interface.

In other words, resolve the situation with the principle of least surprise ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment ). If another programmer on the project (or you, yourself, in some months' time) would ordinarily expect an instance of EscalationMapper to return a sole IContract, and so would be surprised to see it return an IEnumerable, then use an adapter ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern ).  If, conversely, they'd be surprised to see it return a single item, then change the interface.

Comment: Upvote for Principle of least astonishment. Learned something new.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Abion47 and @chrylis comments - 0 or 1 items is a perfectly valid case for an collection of items.

However - if you disagree and still want a way to convey a single element without `IEnumerable` semantics, you could overload `Get` with a method that takes a single object and returns a single IContract. This would take precedence over the params[] overload, since `object` would be a better match for a single input than `params[] object`.

This would look like:

```
public interface IMapper
{
    IContract Get(object input);
    IEnumerable<IContract> Get(params object[] input);
}
```

Assuming a `null` value means not found, your calling code would become:

```
var escalationMapper = _factory.GetEscalationMapper();

//we only get one object with a list of triggers but the interface returns a list. Change the interface? 
var escalation = escalationMapper.Get(trackingGroupCode);

_factory.Release(escalationMapper);

response = Request.CreateResponse(contract == null ? HttpStatusCode.NotFound : HttpStatusCode.OK, contract);
```

I have to caution that it feels odd suggesting this, and I think it introduces dishonesty into the interface. I also think there is great potential to break any existing code that also calls the interface with a single input.

As for replacing `object`, you could always add some marker interface like `IContractInput` and pass that into `Get` instead of `object`:

```
public interface IContractInput { /* Intentionally empty */ }
```

And then, mark any input class with `IContractInput`:

```
public class SomeInput : IContractInput { /* implementation.. */ }
```

That way the methods could be strongly typed to take `IContractInput` instead of a generic `object` type.

Comment: Depending on how many other places `IMapper` is implemented, adding an additional method to the interface might not be feasible. This is especially true if this is for a library that other parties are using - adding another method will force every implementing class to implement that method, which will break compatibility and force a rewrite.

Comment: I would also like to point out that in OP's example, the input to `Get` is still a collection of objects, not a single object, so changing the method to accept a single object is going to also change the behavior. It's also worth mentioning that, in that sense, a single object parameter and a single `IContract` object returned is basically an overly verbose casting method.

Comment: @Abion47 You have good points about breaking compatibility. That isn't something I considered, and adds to my concerns about introducing something like this. We can't really tell from the original example what is being passed to `Get` though, since the question doesn't provide information about the type of `trackingGroupCode`.

Comment: It is possible to introduce this kind of behavior without breaking compatibility. See my answer.